# CollectionView binding does not work correctly

Tags: xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my .Net MAUI app, I have a viewmodel VideoChatPageModel that contains the following observable properties:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private LanguageViewModel _selectedLanguage;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<LanguageViewModel> _languages = new()
    {
        new LanguageViewModel { LanguageName = "English", FlagImage = "flag_united_kingdom.png", LanguageCode = "en" },
        new LanguageViewModel { LanguageName = "Spanish", FlagImage = "flag_spain.png", LanguageCode = "es" },
        new LanguageViewModel { LanguageName = "French", FlagImage = "flag_france.png", LanguageCode = "fr" }
    };
```

Here is the LanguageViewModel class:

```
public class LanguageViewModel
{
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get;set; }
    public string FlagImage { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following CollectionView on the page:

```
             <CollectionView 
                    Margin="5,5,5,15"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView Padding="5" >
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,3*">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FlagImage}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding LanguageName}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

For some reason, it does not compile:

> Error XFC0045 Binding: Property "FlagImage" not found on
> "Features.VideoChat.VideoChatPageModel".

It is clearly looking for the property not in the LanguageViewModel class, but in the VideoChatPageModel, which is the binding context for the whole page:

```
public VideoChatPage(VideoChatPageModel pageModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = pageModel;
}
```

But why does it behave so?
If I replace the CollectionView with the following picker, it works:

```
            <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding LanguageName}">                    
            </Picker>
```

Comment: you need to add a `x:DataType` to `DataTemplate` (presumably you already have one on the page)

Comment: @Jason Thank you, it works. Please make this an answer, and I will mark it.

Comment: After you've iterated on your own LanguageViewModel, you'll learn that you can actually do everything you need with CultureInfo. For instance, the flag, can be done with `"{Binding LCID, StringFormat='flag_{0}.png'}"`. https://github.com/stephenquan/Toolkit.Maui.Localization/blob/8c92e4adf010cd42e95d471b0cad5c22cb6c51be/Toolkit.Maui.Localization.Sample/MainPage.xaml#L70 and https://github.com/stephenquan/Toolkit.Maui.Localization/tree/main/Toolkit.Maui.Localization.Sample/Resources/Images

Comment: @StephenQuan Stephen, I am not sure I understand. How can using CultureInfo help with my specific issue? Thank  you!

Comment: @DavidShochet I simply mentioned that the LanguageViewModel class is unnecessary since the CultureInfo class from System.Globalization can be adapted to do a similar job. It's a question of why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add an `x:DataType` to the `DataTemplate` so it knows what the type of its `BindingContext` is

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify my comment about `LanguageViewModel` can be replaced by `CultureInfo`, you can initialize it just by passing a locale name in the constructor and it will automatically populate other useful properties such as `NativeName`, `EnglishName`, `LCID`, `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` and so forth. You can use any of those parameters to generate a flag filename.

Here's a working example:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs ...
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
```

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs ...
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private CultureInfo _selectedLanguage;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<CultureInfo> _languages = new List<CultureInfo>()
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
    };
}
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml ... -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:g="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
             x:Class="maui_language_picker.MainPage">
    <CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="g:CultureInfo">
                <ContentView Padding="5" >
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,3*">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding LCID, StringFormat='flag_{0}.png'}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding NativeName}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                    </Grid>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

And you create your flag resources as:

- Resources/Images/flag_1033.svg // en-US
- Resources/Images/flag_3082.svg // es-ES
- Resources/Images/flag_1036.svg // fr-FR

You can limit the flag resolution to conservatively by setting `BaseSize` in your csproj, e.g.

```xml
<!-- Images -->
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\flag_*.svg" BaseSize="60,40" />
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-7.0
- https://github.com/stephenquan/StackOverflow.Maui/tree/main/StackOverflow.Maui.Mvvm.CultureInfoFlag

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a nice way, and I am going to use it. Jason's answer was still first, and it does resolve the problem. I upvoted your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @DavidShochet no problem. I am happy that you're able to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on iOS. E.g. for language "en" DisplayName, NativeName, Name etc all have the same value "en"...

Comment: Try a full language code, such as "en-US" instead of "en".

Comment: I tried it, and it did not help...

Comment: It appears you need to enable .NET 8 Hybrid Globalization. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14148#issuecomment-1762747600 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#hybridglobalization-mode-on-iostvosmaccatalyst

Comment: Good to know, thank you!